# Export variables or set them in .profile?

Tags: .profile

I am installing Apache Maven 3.1 on Ubuntu Desktop 10.04.

The installation page http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation, in the section "Unix-based Operating Systems", states to export several variables:

```
export M2_HOME=/home/hduser/workspace/apache-maven-3.1.0
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

When I logout, and later login, I will lose those variables.  So wouldnt it make more sense to set those variables in .profile so that when I later login I will still have those variables set?  Why doesnt the instruction page state that, or are they expecting I will have the common sense to do that on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` just makes the variables survive when another shell is called.  A typical situation where another shell is called is when you invoke a script.

You'll definitely want to copy all those `export` statements in your `.profile` so that not only are they there when you login, but also exist in any subshells you may spawn through executing scripts and such.

I'd say this is a basic Unix thing.

Look at your current `.profile` - you'll likely already see an `export PATH=` statement in it.